# Isolate devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

In my home, I have some devices connected to the internet, but my father is not concerned about security, so I want to isolate all his devices (one of them use cable) and deny ALL possible traffic between his devices and another devices in my network.

My network infrastructure has only one router connected to the internet, and all devices connected to this router. I have another router but I'm not using it, and both without "guest network" and that don't supports flashed-bios, like OpenWRT or Tomato. Is there a way I can this type of isolation?

Answer (score 0):

Plug the second router’s WAN port in to the existing network, and move all “protected” devices over to the LAN/WiFi of the second router.

Devices on the “protected” network can reach devices on the unprotected network, but not vice versa unless you port forward on router 2.

Both networks have to have different network addresses, some routers may use the same default network address and this might cause issues if not changed.

It is technically still possible for devices on the unprotected network to disrupt the internet traffic on the protected network. But as long as you’re using an encrypted connection (most are now) there isn’t a security risk.

Comment: So, the devices on the first router cannot reach devices on the second router? And I don't understand what you mean in "unless you port forward on router 2".

Comment: @Mycroft think about this as if you have a single router, as you do now. Devices on your internal network can access all devices on the “external” network (the internet) but external devices can not access your internal network without port forwarding. This is called NAT. The exact same thing happens if you plug in another router. Except the “external” network is network #1 from the perspective of router 2.

Comment: Thank you. How I can test if connection from router 1 to router 2 is disabled? I'm afraid this configuration could be by default.